# Этот проект требует переноса - Visual Studio 2019 и Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

С напарником столкнулся с проблемой. При переносе проекта через Git у моего друга не отображаются файлы в проекте и он не может нормально кодить. У меня же всё нормально и даже клонируя у себя тоже всё норм. Он юзает VS 2019, я - VS 2017.

После этого я решил себе поставить Visual studio 2019 и также с нуля клонировать проект: у меня нормально, а у него - нет.

Самое интересное, что у него при перекидывании архивом, то всё в норме открывается. Я предполагаю, что проблемы с Git, но почему тогда у него только (использует стандартный git от VS 2019)

Также пытались (как во многих решениях при не отображении подсказок) открыть в "External tools", где редакторы кода, через Browse открыть VS 2019. Не получилось

Прикрепляю скрин у моего товарища:

[image]

Comment: Склонируйте репозиторий в отдельную папку и попробуйте открыть там. Также удостоверьтесь, что у вас и у напарника установлены те же самые компоненты студии.

Comment: У него нормально открывается архивом (просто архив через google drive). Компонент важен только один - для Unity (что у меня и у него есть). Но через Git у него не открывается то, что нужно. Мы оба клонировали репозиторий в отдельную папку

Comment: Если у него архивом открывается, а через git нет, значит не все нужные файлы сохранены в репозитории.

Comment: А почему тогда у меня при клонировании в пустое место всё нормально открывается. Единственное, что стоит в `.gitignore` - это *.bit . Но всё остальное перекидывается без всяких проблем и открывается у меня без проблем

Comment: Этого я не могу знать. Но если вы говорите, что у вашего напарника из архива открывается, а из git - нет, то ищите разницу между архивом и git репозиторием.